# Find index of a given CSV row

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a CSV file, and I can search through it like this:

```
csv.find {|row| row[0] == 'MB_ID'}
```

It returns an object:

```
#<CSV::Row "MB_ID":"MB_ID">
```

How can I get the index of the row relatively to the CSV File ? 
I tried `.index` but didn't work.

Here is a sample:

```
MB_ID
CATEGORIE_ARTICLE_ARTICLE_ID
COMMENTAIRE_ID
CLUB_ID
MESSAGE_ID
EXP_ID
ADH_ID
PRO_ID
LA_ID
SA_ID
```

So the expected result would be 1 for "MB_ID" (or 0 depending on how CSV are indexed).

I read the file using:

```
csv = File.read("foreign.csv")
csv = CSV.parse(csv, :headers => true)
```

Comment: `csv.index {|row| row[0] == 'MB_ID'}` seems to work for me.

Comment: Could you include a sample CSV file and your expected result?

Comment: How do you read the CSV file?

Comment: @Stefan also edited

Comment: try csv=CSV.read('file.csv')

Comment: @GrahamSlick your example data doesn't really work, because it would treat `MB_ID` as the header row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`index` only works for arrays. For enumerables like `CSV::Table`, you have to use [`find_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_index):

```
csv.find_index { |row| row[0] == 'MB_ID' } #=> 0
```